# How to find missing records for a given range?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a following table as below

```
Country  Level      Code
USA      Level A    10
USA      Level A    11
USA      Level A    12
USA      Level A    13
USA      Level A    14
USA      Level B    20
USA      Level B    21
USA      Level B    22
USA      Level B    23
USA      Level B    24
```

and

```
Level      Min Code     Max Code
Level A    10           15
Level B    20           25
```

I need to find if Table 1 has all the codes between the range defined in Table 2, if some thing is missing, i want that to an output of a query. Please help

**In case of above example Level A 15, Level B 25 is missing**

Comment: There's no "create sequence" in MS Access, so you probably need to create a table with all numbers you may encounter, and then join against that one.

Comment: If your table has more than just a few thousand rows, I'd recommend **not** to do this in pure (set-based) sql.  It would be much more efficient to implement a vba function that iterates over the values of the first table and populates a table with the missing records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a class of problem that can be solved with Access SQL by using a "numbers table". This "numbers table" is a table you manually create in Access that contains a column of numeric values (usually sequential) covering a range of values that you will be working with.

(Other more sophisticated implementations of the SQL language allow us to create this sort of table "on the fly", but unfortunately Access SQL doesn't support that so we have to create the table beforehand, either manually or via some VBA code.)

For this example we'll use a table named [Numbers] with a single `Number (Long Integer)` field named [n]. We need it to cover the entire expected range of [Code] values, 10 through 25, so our [Numbers] table will look like this:

```
 n
--
10
11
12
...
24
25
```

(Note that it usually doesn't matter if a "numbers table" contains values *outside* expected range, since the queries that use them often limit the range of values in a WHERE clause someplace, but it is imperative that the "numbers table" *completely covers* the expected range of values.)

Once we have created and populated our [Numbers] table we can start with the query

```
SELECT c.Country, c.Level, Numbers.n AS Code
FROM 
Numbers,
(SELECT DISTINCT [Country], [Level] FROM Codes) c 
INNER JOIN 
CodeRanges cr 
    ON c.Level=cr.Level
WHERE Numbers.n BETWEEN cr.[Min Code] AND cr.[Max Code]
```

which returns all possible codes within the prescribed ranges

```
Country  Level    Code 
-------  -------  ----
USA      Level A    10
USA      Level A    11
USA      Level A    12
USA      Level A    13
USA      Level A    14
USA      Level A    15
USA      Level B    20
USA      Level B    21
USA      Level B    22
USA      Level B    23
USA      Level B    24
USA      Level B    25
```

Now we can find the items in the [Codes] table that are missing from that list by using the above query as a derived table (which I will call "AllCodes"):

```
SELECT [Country], [Level], [Code]
FROM 
    (
        SELECT c.Country, c.Level, Numbers.n AS Code
        FROM 
        Numbers,
        (SELECT DISTINCT [Country], [Level] FROM Codes) c 
        INNER JOIN 
        CodeRanges cr 
            ON c.Level=cr.Level
        WHERE Numbers.n BETWEEN cr.[Min Code] AND cr.[Max Code]
    ) AllCodes
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM Codes
        WHERE Codes.Country=AllCodes.Country 
            AND Codes.Level=AllCodes.Level 
            AND Codes.Code=AllCodes.Code
    )
```

which returns

```
Country  Level    Code
-------  -------  ----
USA      Level A    15
USA      Level B    25
```

Comment: yes i know but, its a long list and have more than 26000 records and keeps getting updated every month and difficult to maintain and validate, so wanted to keep it simple by range

Comment: @Sathish Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. Is there some problem with this answer?

Comment: Your answer gives me exactly what i want, however i need to create a table with all the codes instead of range. In our case its many combination and more codes (aprox 26000) and increasing

Comment: @Sathish We can continue this conversation [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32578/chat-between-gord-thompson-and-sathish) if you like.

Comment: @Sathish RE: your latest chat comment - Yes, you need to create the [Numbers] table manually. (I have updated my answer to clarify.)

Answer (score 1):

Generating the missing codes is a real pain, especially in Access.  You need a list of all possible codes, and then find the ones that are not in the range.  Generating such a list is not trivial in Access.

To find if anything is missing, you can just count:

```
select r.*
from ranges r left join
     (select level, count(distinct code) as NumCodes
      from t
     ) t 
     on r.level = t.level
where t.NumCodes < (r.MaxCode - r.MinCode)+1
```